# How do I block traffic between two interfaces using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I want to block all traffic between my two interfaces. I am using erpxe on the eth1 interface and it seems that when I boot into erpxe, it pulls an ip address from eth0. How can I accomplish this via iptables?

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:b5:fb:d7:ca  
          inet addr:192.168.2.129  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:b5ff:fefb:d7ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32094 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22013025 (20.9 MiB)  TX bytes:4120708 (3.9 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:b5:f6:a2:dd  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:b5ff:fef6:a2dd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1304135 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:25538091 (24.3 MiB)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say you think eth1 pulls an IP from eth0? Is eth0 a DHCP authority? eth0 and eth1 have IP addresses in completely different networks. Unless you have a route that allows traffic to go from 10.0.0.0/24 to 192.168.2.0/24 traffic cannot route from one network to the other so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with iptables.

Comment: I would disable routing. Check cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward and check if it is enabled

Comment: I did that and it comes back with a "1", so I am assuming it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Eth0 is on my LAN and I am using eth1 for my ERPXE service. Eth1 is using DHCP so every time a pc boots from PXE, it pulls an address from eth1. Unfortunately my pc tries to pull an IP address from eth1, but ends up pulling one from eth0 which isn't a DHCP server.